# Webcam incorrectly identified in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, skype, webcam

I have two webcams that I have used for a number of years (more than ten) in different versions of Ubuntu, without any problems (just plug and play). The last time they worked was about six months ago (I don't do videoconferencing a lot), now I cannot get either to work properly.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Mate on a desktop. The first camera is a Creative Labs! Optia that is listed in `lsusb` as:

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0402:5606 ALi Corp. M5606 Video Camera Controller [UVC]
```

If this is the only camera physically plugged in, there is no outptut to

```
$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

According to http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/, the Device ID for this brand and model should have been `041e:4057`, so I am assuming it is incorrectly identified and is not loading the correct driver. No software recognizes it as a consequence. I am at a complete loss here.

The second camera is a Logitech QuickCam that seems to load the correct driver and is recognized by `lsusb` as

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:092c Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Chat
```

and

```
$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 mar 19 15:32 /dev/video0
```

It works in guvcview, camorama and VLC. It is not found by cheese, skype or any web browser.

None of the answered questions I found in my google search seem to replicate my exact problem.

I would appreciate any guidance I can get from the community. Thanks a lot for your time and consideration.